# PHP: Calculate average value of an array if have more than one element

Tags: php, arrays, average, median

I must to calculate the value of an array taken from a query only if had more than one element, else I must to return the value of the element, I'm using this code:

```
function calculate_average($arr) {
  if (count($arr) === 1) {
    $average = $arr;
  } else {
    sort($arr);
    $count = count($arr); //count items in array
    $sum = array_sum($arr); //sum of numbers in array
    $median = $sum / $count; //divide sum by count
    $average = ceil($median); //convert number in excess value
  }
   return $average;
}
```

And work when there is two or more value, but return NULL when there is only one value, why?

Thanks to all who want to partecipate.

Comment: Why not doing everything in a single line, like this: `return ceil(array_sum($arr) / count($arr));` ?

Comment: You're right, I'm usually do all the operation line per line, so anyone can understand who is doing, your expression surely more correct

Answer (score 1):

As it's been said, to do it the way you're trying to, you need to access the first element of your array like

```
$average = $arr[0];
```

However, your method of calculating the average will still work for an array with one element.  It'll just work out to x/1.

```
function calculate_average($arr) {
  $count = count($arr); //count items in array
  $sum = array_sum($arr); //sum of numbers in array
  $median = $sum / $count; //divide sum by count
  $average = ceil($median); //round number

  return $average;
}
```

Comment: This don't work, i got a null response when have only one item

Comment: It works for me.  What version of PHP are you running?  Can you show the data you're testing to see if there's something else weird happening?  Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/493a562f2dfd585efdf87c38607cd0980d146ce5

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
function calculate_average($arr) {
  if (count($arr) === 1) {
    $average = $arr[0];
  } else {
    sort($arr);
    $count = count($arr); //count items in array
    $sum = array_sum($arr); //sum of numbers in array
    $median = $sum / $count; //divide sum by count
    $average = ceil($median); //convert number in excess value
  }
   return $average;
}
```

Comment: you are actually assigning the array $average = $arr; to variable $average so it should be $average = $arr[0];

Comment: and ofcourse there is no need to sort the array, I think! unless you have a specific reason for the same